# Constructing a group with subsets

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Given the set $S=\{0,1,2\}$, it has been asked to prove that it is not a group under the operation $\max(x,y)$. It can be done. Then they ask to identify $3$ subsets of $S$ which are 'groups' under the operation $\max(x,y)$.

How to choose the subsets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $\max(x,x) = x$ for all $x \in S$. So if $(S', \max)$ is a group, we must have $|S'| = 1$ (for otherwise there is no identity). That is $\{0\}$, $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$ are the subsets looked for.

Comment: can we have a single element with a BINARY operation and call it a group?

Comment: Yes ... the operation is then the(!) map $\circ \colon \{*\} \times \{*\} \to \{*\}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** A singleton is always a group.